# ¿Como implementar combinaciones de teclas?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017

Trabajo con C#, Windows Forms necesito implementar en el evento KeyDow del formulario la siguiente combinación de tecla Alt + C lo he intentado pero no he logrado conseguirlo.

```
if (e.KeyCode == e.Alt && Keys.C )
```

No es el camino, ¿Como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: necesita ser con keyDown forzozamente?

Comment: Si ahí manejo las combinaciones de teclas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (e.KeyData == ( Keys.C |Keys.Alt)){
   //lo que necesites hacer
}
```

Nota: no olvides poner el parámetro de **KeyPreview** del form en true, para que esto funcione.

Comment: Muchas gracias!